# facebook logout issue in ios

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, logout, io-redirection

I am integrating facebook login implementation in my ios app. I have followed below tutorial to implement facebook login implementation.

https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/tree/master/FBLoginCustomUISample

I have successfully completed login  process but the problem is Login button becomes Logout button after successful authentication. But I want to implement Logout button in a separate view(`CustomViewController`).

The main thing is after successful login authentication user has to be redirected to separate viewController where I need to place logout button through that user can be logged out.But in this tutorial Login and logout implemented in the same view for same button. suggest me if you know any sample code or link like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that way, why are you using the sample? Integrating facebook is a very simple job if you follow the step wise tutorials from the official [developer's guide](http://developers.facebook.com).

Read carefully and implement [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/).

Comment: I have implemented facebook integration successfully butafter login authentication login button becomes logout and control reaches same viewController where Login process starts. Many developers might have implemented this functionality that's why I am asking. If you have implemented login and logout buttons in a different views please let me know.

Comment: See, this login, logout with different views- its all absurd. You can implement anything anywhere you wish, at least try to understand the code. Simply dont create logout on that page, make it on some other, or you can even ignore this logout if you wish

Comment: After facebook authentication control reaches to same view controller. But I need to be redirected to some viewController  after authentication. I tried but I could not. I am sorry if I irritated with my question.